# SQL check if column values varies

Tags: mysql, sql, unique

lets say we have two tables with 1 to n relation

```
group
--+-------+
id|name   |
--+-------+
1 | GROUP1|
2 | GROUP2|
3 | GROUP3|
--+-------+

unit
--+-----+-----+------+
id|group|value|status|
--+-----+-----+------+
 1| 1   |  0  |  0   |
 2| 1   |  20 |  0   |
 3| 1   |  5  |  0   |
 4| 2   |  1  |  1   |
 5| 2   |  3  |  1   |
 6| 2   |  0  |  1   |
 7| 3   |  5  |  1   |
 8| 3   |  8  |  0   |
 9| 3   |  6  |  0   |
```

How can I know, if some row is unique in the group? And if not unique, what value is it?
For example:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT `group`.id,
    `group`.name,
    MIN(unit.value) AS 'min',
    MAX(unit.value) AS 'max',
    isUnique(unit.status) AS 'status'
FROM unit JOIN `group` ON unit.`group` = `group`.id
GROUP BY `group`.id
ORDER BY `group`.id
```

should return:

```
--+-------+---+---+------+
id|name   |min|max|status|
--+-------+---+---+------+
1 | GROUP1|0  |20 | all 0|
2 | GROUP2|0  |3  | all 1|
3 | GROUP3|5  |8  | both |
                  (status is in string just to ilustarate returned values)
```

Comment: group by should be used before order by other wise it will give error

Comment: sorry, i wrote that from my mind

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is clever and elegant, but CASE gives more freedom, i dont know witch answer is better. How about votes? :)

Comment: I depends on you and also on performance check answers and pick answer which is best in performance then select that answer

Comment: It does not depend on my because in my case performance is not the matter, and i will use @echo_Me answer, though i like GROUP_CONCAT more. I don't think performance would vary too much, and i dont have so much data to test it. So in general case i sincerely dont know witch to chose, though I might be overdoing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` with distinct status per group

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT `group`.id,
    `group`.name,
    MIN(unit.value) AS 'min',
    MAX(unit.value) AS 'max',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT unit.status) AS 'status'
FROM unit JOIN `group` ON unit.`group` = `group`.id
GROUP BY `group`.id
ORDER BY `group`.id
```

Results will be

```
--+-------+---+---+------+
id|name   |min|max|status|
--+-------+---+---+------+
1 | GROUP1|0  |20 |  0   |
2 | GROUP2|0  |3  |  1   |
3 | GROUP3|5  |8  | 1,0  |
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66cfc/6)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
SELECT 
DISTINCT `group`.id,
`group`.name,
MIN(unit.value) AS 'min',
MAX(unit.value) AS 'max',
CASE WHEN MAX(unit.status) = MIN(unit.status) 
    Then unit.status Else 'Both' END AS 'status'
FROM unit JOIN `group` ON unit.`group` = `group`.id
GROUP BY `group`.id
ORDER BY `group`.id
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66cfc/5)